# Gradle sync failed: Cannot cast object '.../classes/test/release' with class 'java.io.File' to class 'org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection'

Tags: android, gradle, synchronization, build.gradle

I got this problem when i try to sync my project with gradle files. I got this error when I updated Android Studio to version 3.1.3.
My **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
}
```

Comment: It says something about casting. Can you post both of your full gradle scripts please?

Comment: Try once with  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

Comment: I already find out what was wrong. I was using retrolambdas and there was conflict with Android Studio 3.1 built in features.